# How to add commits from local git repo to remote, where remote recently had files removed from history?

Tags: git, github

I recently had to move a git repo to an internally run github platform at work. To do so, I had to follow [these instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove files that were too large from all history. In parallel, I had made several commits to my local copy of the git repo before the move. How can I run these commits on the remote repo without re-introducing the history with the large files? I'm hesitant to just start trying stuff for fear of accidentally losing my local commits or tainting the remote's history.

Comment: The solution you presented don't remove the files from the complete history, but just for this particular commit. If you want to remove it completely you need to rewrite history with a interactive rebase and also remove the 'introduction' of the file.

Comment: @ckruczek I apologize for the confusion. I meant the instructions at the bottom of that page, which actually redirect to another page. I replaced the link with the new page in my question. Thank you for letting me know.